# Can I Turn Off Hardware Accelerated Canvas From Javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, extjs4

Chrome 18 seems to have a pretty big problem with Ext 4 charts.  Is there any way I can disable the hardware accelerated canvas?  (I'm pretty sure that's what the bug is from) or will I have to wait for someone to release a patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line switch: `--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas`

Added that at the end of my Chrome shortcut target and checked chrome://gpu/

> Canvas: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled.

Comment: I don't think command line switch qualifies as a solution from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This temporary fix may be helpful:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186171-Beta3-Weird-stuff-happening-on-Chrome-18-19&p=768834&viewfull=1#post768834

Answer (score 0):

GPUAcceleration can be disabled with the CanvasContext2D-option `willReadFrequently`.

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext):

> `willReadFrequently` A boolean value that indicates whether or not a lot of read-back operations are planned. This will force the use of a software (instead of hardware accelerated) 2D canvas and can save memory when calling getImageData() frequently.

Usage:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
```