# Disabling hardware acceleration of 2d rendering on html5 canas in Android browser

Tags: html5-canvas

I executed javascript html5 canvas test on android browser for profiling.
To disable hardware acceleration of 2d rendering on html5 canvas in android webbrowser, I configured flag in android browser. (external/packages/apps/Browser ...)

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

However, this configuration doesn't seem to work. 
Can anyone give me some help for this?

Comment: Please humor me, but I'm curious why would you want to turn hardware acceleration off?

Answer (score 1):

When creating my view I add this code, this works for me:

```
    private void fixSignatureDoubleLineIssueOnJb(View root) {
    Log.d(TAG, "API level: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        try {
            Method method = root.getClass().getMethod("setLayerType", int.class, Paint.class);
            method.invoke(root, 0x01/* View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE */, null);

            Log.d(TAG, "hardware accelaration disabled");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to disabled hardware acceleration", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to disabled hardware acceleration", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to disabled hardware acceleration", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to disabled hardware acceleration", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between the Android Canvas, and the html5 canvas. They are two different things. Your code snippet is geared toward the android canvas. Not Html5. I believe the only way to disable hardware acceleration on the browser is by changing the browser settings. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946638/can-i-turn-off-hardware-accelerated-canvas-from-javascript) is an example of Chromes switch.

Comment: The test javascript is in a html file, which is opened in android web browser. When I disabled hw acceleration in  packages/apps/Browser/AndroidManifest.xml, some graphic rendering which doesn't use html5 canvas was sw-rendering (I observed profiles .) But, some 2d rendering using html5 canvas (<canvas> tag) is hw-accelerated. That's why I posted this question. Anyway, thank you for your reference!